# Filetr items using mongotemplate - aggregation in spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, nosql, aggregation-framework, mongotemplate

I am trying to filter the products based on "cashback" offer using filter, but it is not working.Thanks in advance

My sprinboot method is:

```
public List<ProductsObj> getAllCashbackItems() {
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("listOfPromotions").in("cashback"));
    Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
               project().and(filter("listOfPromotions")
                 .as("item")
                 .by(valueOf(
                      "item.promotionName")
                       .equalToValue(
                      "cashback")))
              .as("listOfPromotions")
        );
    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "productsObj", ProductsObj.class).getMappedResults();

}
```

My collection is look alike:

```
[
        {
            "_id": "5be29135f590eb09a079951a",
            "name": "tennis ball",
            "price": "1500",
            "category": "sports",
            "listOfPromotions": [
                {
                    "promotionName": "cashback",
                    "percentage": 12
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "5be29142f590eb09a079951b",
            "name": "volley ball",
            "price": "600",
            "category": "sports",
            "listOfPromotions": [
                {
                    "promotionName": "dham dhamaal",
                    "percentage": 6
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "5be2914ef590eb09a079951c",
            "name": "Dinning table",
            "price": "15000",
            "category": "furnitures",
            "listOfPromotions": [
                {
                    "promotionName": "cashback",
                    "percentage": 6
                },
                {
                    "promotionName": "dham dhamaal",
                    "percentage": 10
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

---

My ProductsObj POJO class is :-

---

```
@Document(collection = "productsObj")
 public class ProductsObj {
@Id
public ObjectId _id;
@Indexed
public String name;
public String price;
public String category;
public List<Promotion> listOfPromotions;
 //constructors
  //getters and setters
  }
```

I am trying filter the object based on above mentioned criteria (i.e., cashback offer) In Promotions entity class contains promotionName and percentage.

Comment: which ORM you are using?

Comment: mongodb raw query will work for you?

Comment: What part is not working ? Your query looks correct. Can you show us the productobj pojo class ?

Comment: I have updated the pojo @Veeram

Comment: I am using springdata @alok

Comment: Thanks Guys.. I found solution. I tried with aggregation but i resolved with simple criteria query.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution instead of simple criteria query i tried aggregation.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getcashbackitems", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<ProductsObj> getAllCashbackItems() {
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("listOfPromotions.promotionName").is("cashback"));
    return mongoTemplate.find(query, ProductsObj.class);
}
```

Thanks for your responses :)